# Holoviews: Plot frame(s) dimensions and aspect ratio

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I am currently desperately trying out to align three images with different sizes in a gridlike layout.

Essentially, I would like to insert three raster images of different shapes. I would like to be able to define their boundary and aspect ratio of each raster independently that they are not stretched in one dimension. However, I fail to find a fix doing that.

My code snipplet:

```html
import holoviews as hv
import numpy as np
hv.extension('bokeh')
%%opts Raster [show_frame=False shared_axes=False]

hv.Layout(hv.Raster(np.eye(100,100),group='t1') +
 hv.Raster(np.eye(100,20),group='t2') + 
 hv.Raster(np.eye(20,100),group='t3')).cols(2)
```

Which produces the following:
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IuCV.png)

Is there any way to define each raster image bounding box individually in a layout?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution after searching through the API.

width and height can be adjusted individually by opts:

```
hv.Raster(np.eye(100,100),group='t1').opts(plot=dict(width=500, height=500))
```